# merge parent and child attributes using xslt based on attribute values

Tags: xml, xslt, merge, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have an xml file which contains the following markup, I know the format of this file is not correct but that's how the file is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mbean code="org.book.mybooks"
   name="mycompany.props.jndi:name=mybookprops">
    <attribute name="CombineProps" serialDataType="jbxb">
        <jndi:bindings xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0"
                     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                     xs:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0 resource:jndi-binding-service_1_0.xsd">
            <jndi:binding name="books/mybooks/cartoon/comics">
                <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                        @Value@
                </jndi:value>
            </jndi:binding>
            <jndi:binding name="abc/ebooks/onebook/action">
                <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                        @Value@
                </jndi:value>
            </jndi:binding>
            <jndi:binding name="abc/ibooks/twobook/romance">
                <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                        @Value@
                </jndi:value>
            </jndi:binding>

        </jndi:bindings>
    </attribute>
    <mbean code="org.book.mybooks"
          name="mycompany.props.jndi:name=mybookprops">
        <attribute name="CombineProps" serialDataType="jbxb">
            <jndi:bindings xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0"
                        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                        xs:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0 resource:jndi-binding-service_1_0.xsd">
                <jndi:binding name="books/mybooks/cartoon/comics">
                    <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                        @New_Value@
                    </jndi:value>
                </jndi:binding>
                <jndi:binding name="abc/ebooks/onebook/action">
                    <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                        @New_Value@
                    </jndi:value>
                </jndi:binding>
                <jndi:binding name="books/new/books/cartoon">
                    <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                        @Value@
                    </jndi:value>
                </jndi:binding>
            </jndi:bindings>
        </attribute>
    </mbean>
</mbean>
```

If you observe the file, it contain a child element called `<mbean>` with in a parent element `<mbean>`, so i want to remove this parent-child and make a one single element `<mbean>all parent elements and child elements</mbean>` file.

I have searched few questions in stackoverflow but it looks like they are not exactly related to the problem that i am having right now. Can someone give an idea how to work on this solution using either by xslt 1.0 or 2.0.

This is the final output that i am expecting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mbean code="org.book.mybooks"
   name="mycompany.props.jndi:name=mybookprops">
    <attribute name="CombineProps" serialDataType="jbxb">
        <jndi:bindings xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0"
                     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                     xs:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0 resource:jndi-binding-service_1_0.xsd">
            <jndi:binding name="books/mybooks/cartoon/comics">
                <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                        @New_Value@
                </jndi:value>
            </jndi:binding>
            <jndi:binding name="abc/ebooks/onebook/action">
                <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                        @New_Value@
                </jndi:value>
            </jndi:binding>
            <jndi:binding name="abc/ibooks/twobook/romance">
                <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                        @Value@
                </jndi:value>
            </jndi:binding>
            <jndi:binding name="books/new/books/cartoon">
                <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                        @Value@
                </jndi:value>
            </jndi:binding>
        </jndi:bindings>
    </attribute>
</mbean>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Maybe you are confusing xml attributes (http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp) with the attribute element in your xml.  "if parent is having same attribute as child attribute but with different values, overwrite the parent attribute with child attribute"...What do you mean by this?  Do you mean different code and name attributes for the mbean element.  Or do you mean different attribute element?

Comment: added extra element to the parent element(please check the updated xml file and expected output.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple change the XPATH as I commented in the previous answer. I hope you serve.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0"  >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" /> 
    <xsl:template match="mbean/mbean">  
    <mbean code="org.book.mybooks"
   name="mycompany.props.jndi:name=mybookprops">
    <attribute name="CombineProps" serialDataType="jbxb"> 
    <jndi:bindings xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0"
                     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                     xs:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0 resource:jndi-binding-service_1_0.xsd">    
        <xsl:copy-of select="attribute/jndi:bindings/jndi:binding"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="Mbean">
          <xsl:with-param name="bindings" select="attribute/jndi:bindings/jndi:binding"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        </jndi:bindings>
        </attribute>           
     </mbean>   
    </xsl:template>   
    <xsl:template name="Mbean">
       <xsl:param name="bindings"/>
       <xsl:for-each select="/mbean/attribute/jndi:bindings/jndi:binding">
                <xsl:variable name="currentBinding" select="self::node()"/>  
                <xsl:if test="not(@name[. = $bindings/@name])">
                          <xsl:copy-of select="self::node()"/>
                </xsl:if>                        
       </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="text()"></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: gr8, every thing seems to be expected, except `<jndi:binding xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="books/mybooks/cartoon/comics">` is it possible to get this as `<jndi:binding name="books/mybooks/cartoon/comics">`

Comment: Sorry is missing node jndi:bindings

Comment: the line `xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ` to be removed from <jndi:binding xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="books/mybooks/cartoon/comics">, please see the expected output in the question. Thanks again.

Comment: namespace that are cuastiones can change without having to expect to put exactly the XSLT

Comment: moreover the result comes correptamente <mbean xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0" code="org.book.mybooks" name="mycompany.props.jndi:name=mybookprops">
 <attribute name="CombineProps" serialDataType="jbxb">
  <jndi:bindings xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0 resource:jndi-binding-service_1_0.xsd">
   <jndi:binding name="books/mybooks/cartoon/comics">
    <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                        @New_Value@
                    </jndi:value>
   </jndi:binding>

Comment: Thanks for your help its working, I have accepted the answer, when you get a chance can you also please look at my other question which is pretty much similar to this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18450728/merge-two-elements-using-xslt-based-on-attribute-values

Answer (score 0):

You can change paths. First write parent nodes and then the children who does not have the dad.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0">

  <!--Put missing nodes as mbean-->

    <xsl:template match="mbean">          
        <xsl:copy-of select="attribute/jndi:bindings/jndi:binding"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="childMbean">
          <xsl:with-param name="bindings" select="attribute/jndi:bindings/jndi:binding"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>    

    <xsl:template name="childMbean">
       <xsl:param name="bindings"/>
       <xsl:for-each select="mbean/attribute/jndi:bindings/jndi:binding">
                <xsl:variable name="currentBinding" select="self::node()"/>  
                <xsl:if test="not(@name[. = $bindings/@name])">
                          <xsl:copy-of select="self::node()"/>
                </xsl:if>                        
       </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: the output is missing opening tag and closing tag `<mbean code="org.book.mybooks" name="mycompany.props.jndi:name=mybookprops">`

Comment: also if I add extra element to the parent element(please check the updated question), that extra element is not copying to the output file.

Comment: Somehow the this code is not working, did you get a chance try this code with the given xml. I get the following output: `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jndi:binding xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="books/mybooks/cartoon/comics"><jndi:value type="java.lang.String">@Value@</jndi:value></jndi:binding><jndi:binding xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="abc/ebooks/onebook/action"><jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
@Value@</jndi:value></jndi:binding>`

Comment: With the input XML and XSL I suggested I get  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><jndi:binding xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="books/mybooks/cartoon/comics"><jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                        @Value@
                </jndi:value></jndi:binding><jndi:binding xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="abc/ebooks/onebook/action">

Comment: <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                        @Value@
                </jndi:value></jndi:binding><jndi:binding xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="abc/ibooks/twobook/romance"><jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                        @Value@
                </jndi:value></jndi:binding>

Comment: <jndi:binding xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="books/new/books/cartoon"><jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
                        @Value@
                    </jndi:value></jndi:binding>

Comment: tested in XNLSpy try again

Comment: Is obtained the comics, action, romance and cartoon that are not repeated in the name of the jndi: binding children

Comment: Right, i get the same output, which is not the expected one, can you please get me the one that is similar to Expected Output file that i have mentioned in the question, Thanks and appreciate your help.