# merge two elements using xslt based on attribute values

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

This is how my source file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<book>
    <mbean code="org.book.mybooks"  name="mycompany.props.jndi:name=mybookprops">   
        <attribute name="bookprops">
            abc.mybook.onebook=@Value@
            def.mybook.twobook=@Value@
            ghi.myebook.threebook=@Value@
        </attribute>
    </mbean>
    <book>
        <mbean code="org.book.mybooks"  name="mycompany.props.jndi:name=mybookprops">   
            <attribute name="bookprops">
            abc.mybook.onebook=@New_Value@
            def.mybook.twobook=@New_Value@
            ghi.myebook.fourbook=@Value@

            </attribute>
        </mbean>
    </book>
</book>
```

I am looking to get merge two attributes to one and copy all the matching lines with new variable `@New_Value@` and copy all other non matching lines to the end of the file.

This problem is pretty much similar to the question that i have posted earlier [merge parent and child attributes using xslt based on attribute values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389467/merge-parent-and-child-attributes-using-xslt-based-on-attribute-values) only difference is the format of the content in the XML file.

Based on the solution that was provided in the above URL, I have tweaked my xsl to get work this new XML file, here is the xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0"  >
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" /> 
    <xsl:template match="book/book"> 
        <book>
            <mbean code="org.book.mybooks" name="mycompany.props.jndi:name=mybookprops">    
                <attribute name="bookprops">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="mbean/attribute/node()"/>
                    <xsl:call-template name="Mbean">
                        <xsl:with-param name="bindings" select="book/mbean/attribute"/>
                    </xsl:call-template> 
                </attribute>
            </mbean>
        </book>
    </xsl:template>  

    <xsl:template name="Mbean">
        <xsl:param name="bindings"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="/book/mbean/attribute/node()">
            <xsl:variable name="currentBinding" select="self::node()"/>  
            <xsl:if test="not(node()[. = $bindings])">
                <xsl:copy-of select="self::node()"/>
            </xsl:if>                        
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But somehow i was not able to get the expected result, following is the expected result that i am looking for:

```
<book>
    <mbean code="org.book.mybooks"  name="mycompany.props.jndi:name=mybookprops">   
        <attribute name="bookprops">
            abc.mybook.onebook=@New_Value@
            def.mybook.twobook=@New_Value@
            ghi.myebook.threebook=@Value@
            ghi.myebook.fourbook=@Value@
        </attribute>
    </mbean>
</book>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit ugly but it does what you want and sorry if the first time did not understand well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0"  >
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" /> 
    <xsl:template match="book/book"> 
        <book>
            <mbean code="org.book.mybooks" name="mycompany.props.jndi:name=mybookprops">   
            <attribute name="bookprops">                 
                    <xsl:copy-of select="mbean/attribute/text()"/>
                    <xsl:call-template name="Mbean">
                        <xsl:with-param name="bindings" select="mbean/attribute"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="bindingsP" select="/book/mbean/attribute/text()"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>     
             </attribute>           
            </mbean>
        </book>
    </xsl:template>   
    <xsl:template name="Mbean">
        <xsl:param name="bindings"/>
        <xsl:param name="bindingsP"/>          
            <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="contains($bindingsP,'@Value@')">
                          <xsl:if test="not(contains(substring-before($bindingsP,'@Value@'),'@Value@')) and not(contains(substring-before($bindingsP,'@Value@'),'@New_Value@')) and not(contains($bindings,concat(substring-before($bindingsP,'@Value@'),'@Value@')))">
                                <xsl:copy-of select="concat(substring-before($bindingsP,'@Value@'),'@Value@')"/>
                                <xsl:call-template name="Mbean">
                                   <xsl:with-param name="bindings" select="$bindings"/>
                                   <xsl:with-param name="bindingsP" select="substring-after($bindingsP,'@Value@')"/>
                                </xsl:call-template>
                            </xsl:if>                          
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="contains($bindingsP,'@New_Value@')">
                           <xsl:if test="not(contains(substring-before($bindingsP,'@Value@'),'@Value@')) and not(contains(substring-before($bindingsP,'@Value@'),'@New_Value@')) and not(contains($bindings,concat(substring-before($bindingsP,'@New_Value@'),'@New_Value@')))">
                                <xsl:copy-of select="concat(substring-before($bindingsP,'@New_Value@'),'@New_Value@')"/>
                                <xsl:call-template name="Mbean">
                                   <xsl:with-param name="bindings" select="$bindings"/>
                                   <xsl:with-param name="bindingsP" select="substring-after($bindingsP,'@New_Value@')"/>
                                </xsl:call-template>
                            </xsl:if>       

                    </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>    

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: no, please see the output that i have posted in the question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: there should be only one attribute.

Comment: i didn't get the expected output: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<book xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0">
  <mbean code="org.book.mybooks" name="mycompany.props.jndi:name=mybookprops">
    <attribute name="bookprops">
   abc.mybook.onebook=@New_Value@
   def.mybook.twobook=@New_Value@
   ghi.myebook.fourbook=@Value@
   
   abc.mybook.onebook=@Value@
   def.mybook.twobook=@Value@
   ghi.myebook.threebook=@Value@</attribute>
  </mbean>
</book>`

Comment: the XSLT get good the expected result. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<book xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0">
 <mbean code="org.book.mybooks" name="mycompany.props.jndi:name=mybookprops">
  <attribute name="bookprops">
            abc.mybook.onebook=@New_Value@
            def.mybook.twobook=@New_Value@
            ghi.myebook.fourbook=@Value@
            
            abc.mybook.onebook=@Value@ 
            def.mybook.twobook=@Value@ 
            ghi.myebook.threebook=@Value@</attribute>
 </mbean>
</book>

Comment: but this is not the expected result that i am looking for,here is the expected result that i am looking for: `<book>
    <mbean code="org.book.mybooks"  name="mycompany.props.jndi:name=mybookprops">   
        <attribute name="bookprops">
            abc.mybook.onebook=@New_Value@
            def.mybook.twobook=@New_Value@
            ghi.myebook.threebook=@Value@
            ghi.myebook.fourbook=@Value@
        </attribute>
    </mbean>
</book>`

Comment: to make it easy i wrote this question in detail here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18489662/split-nodes-and-assign-them-to-variables-for-matching hope that might help in getting the right output.